# How to set a deserializer delegate class in java file instead of yml file?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-boot-configuration

I set kafka consumer deserializers in application.yml like this:

#### application.yml

```yaml
kafka:
  consumer:
    key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
    value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
    properties.spring:
      json.trusted.packages: '*'
      deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
```

But I want to set them in a java configuration file like this:

#### KafkaConfig.java

```java
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Bean
    public KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class.getName());
        // set delegate deserializer class here
        KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer(properties);
        return kafkaConsumer;
    }
}
```

I can have a deserializer by using ConsumerConfig.class, but I don't know how to set a delegate deserializer class without using magic values.

Comment: You can try this
`consumerConfig.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
consumerConfig.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, <YourValueDeserializer class>.class);`

Basically you can set the actual key & value deserializers in below properties respectively
ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS
ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS

Refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/ErrorHandlingDeserializer.html